# No matching manifest for unknown when pulling microsoft/aspnet

Tags: docker

I have a CentOS 7 with Docker installed on a VirtualBox. I am also new to Docker. When I run:

```
docker pull microsoft/aspnet
```

I get an error:

```
no matching manifest for unknown in the manifest list entries
```

I can see the image listed if I do:

```
docker search aspnet
```

Do I understand this correctly that this image is not suitable to run in Docker on Linux? Or is there an error getting the correct manifest - thus 'unknown' in the error message?

Running below command produces:

```
$ docker info -f '{{.OSType}}/{{.Architecture}}'
linux/x86_64
```

Some additional information - I was able to pull and successfully use `microsoft/dotnet` image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That docker image is based on `Windows Server Core as the base OS` and also uses `IIS` as the web server, that makes it Windows only, you can use `docker pull microsoft/aspnetcore` on Linux. As for `microsoft/dotnet` it's cross platform and i guess it's basically the same as `microsoft/aspnetcore` but without the `ASP` stuff (sorry i'm not that familiar with Windows SDKs and Frameworks).

Comment: Makes sense. I'll read up more on docker and use windows host for this specific task.